# Why do BigQuery policy tagged columns prevent access to other columns when used in a GROUP BY statement?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-data-catalog

We are exploring the use of BigQuery policy tags for implementing column level security. We have discovered that when a column that a user does not have access to is included in a GROUP BY clause then the user cannot access other columns in the GROUP BY clause either.

Let me explain with a contrived example. Imagine we have a table `t` with two columns:

- `t.a`
- `t.b`

These columns have policy tags on them which grant our end users permission to view the data in `t.a` but not the data in `t.b`.

Hence our end users can issue this query:

```sql
select a 
from t
```

but when issuing this query:

```sql
select b 
from t
```

they get an error:

> Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: User does not have permission to access policy tag "policy-tag-name" on column project.dataset.t.b.

This is expected and is by design.

However if a user issues this query:

```sql
select a 
from (
    select a, b 
    from t 
    group by a, b
)
```

then the same error occurs.

Why is this? The user is not accessing any data that they are not allowed to access. I am struggling to comprehend why the group by statement causes this error. Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query does not expose values b, but it would expose some information about b if it were allowed.

E.g. it lets one know how many different values of b each value of a has. Say a is a product id, and b is seller id. Query would show how many separate sellers each product has. But whoever decided to hide sellers probably does not want this. Or a is some employee group (e.g. department or manager id), and b is salary. This query would expose whether they have the same salary. Policy prevents this.

Note that there could be more complex queries where referencing b does not expose anything about b, but policy prevents it anyway. It is also by design - BigQuery plays it safe, and if it cannot prove such reference does not expose any information, it prohibits it.

Comment: Thinking on … it feels like there needs to be a way of us as policy tag administrators being able to inform BigQuery that certain operations negate the policy on a column (or replace it with a new one). For example, we consider emailAddress to be PII data that we cannot expose to data consumers however we’re content with exposing a hash of emailAddress (hashed with a pepper) - how might we inform BigQuery that a column exposed from a view should not propagate the policy tag from the underlying columns? Consider that a feature request 

Comment: Could you suggest it to the team (I don't work on policies or views) - 
https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers is the right place for feature requests.

Comment: Thank you Michael, I found a relevant issue and left a comment upon it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173805886#comment4